# How to get a binary from any file I upload in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

maybe is possible to get a directly binary from any file I upload, for example upload an Image.

At the moment I use:

- 'react-native-image-picker'

but this library return me a object without binary, so, you have any suggestion developers